# Code not working due to line 6, it runs but doesn't work as designed

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random
randomNum=random.randint(1,9999)
print(randomNum)
userGuess=input("Please guess a 4 digit number, if you get it correct, we'll tell you, otherwise we will tell if you got any of the positions of the numbers correct\n")
if userGuess==randomNum:
    print("Congratulations, you guessed the number correctly")
```

Why doesn't last line work after i enter the correct number? I don't think its indentation and I'm confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast `userGuess` as an integer.
i.e.

```py
import random
randomNum=random.randint(1,9999)
print(randomNum)
userGuess=int(input("Please guess a 4 digit number, if you get it correct, we'll tell you, otherwise we will tell if you got any of the positions of the numbers correct\n"))
if userGuess==randomNum:
    print("Congratulations, you guessed the number correctly")
```

Answer (score 1):

By default input is considered as `str` and not the data type of entered value, that's why you need to take the input and covert it to `int` or convert the `randomNum` to `str`.

```
import random
randomNum= str(random.randint(1,9999))
print(randomNum)
userGuess=input("Please guess a 4 digit number, if you get it correct, we'll tell you, otherwise we will tell if you got any of the positions of the numbers correct\n")
if userGuess==randomNum:
    print("Congratulations, you guessed the number correctly")
```

**OR**

```
import random
randomNum=random.randint(1,9999)
print(randomNum)
userGuess=int(input("Please guess a 4 digit number, if you get it correct, we'll tell you, otherwise we will tell if you got any of the positions of the numbers correct\n"))
if userGuess==randomNum:
    print("Congratulations, you guessed the number correctly")
```

Comment: omg i just remembered I keep making this same mistake thank you so much:)